# While adding a new Table column I cannot find any attribute of IF_NOT_EXIST in the Liquibase Script

Tags: liquibase

```
<changeSet author="John" id="addColumn-example"> 
    <addColumn TableName="person" >
        <column name="address"type="varchar(255)"/> 
    </addColumn>  
</changeSet>
```

I cannot find any attribute or something for the above change-set tags which work like below  Expected Query

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS VARCHAR(255);
```

There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` attribute in the Liquibase docs. It only shows `add column`, can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if it's what You are looking for, but I would suggest adding precondition to your changeset.
This will prevent the execution of your changeset if requirements from precondition are not met. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html).

So after that your changeset would look like this:

```
<changeSet author="John" id="addColumn-example">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onFailMessage="Column address already exists!">
        <not>
            <columnExists tableName="person" columnName="address"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <addColumn tableName="person">
        <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

What is worth noticing is negation with **<not>** tag. It is required since we want to check whether a specific column does **not** exists already. Of course You can pick precondition onFail strategy which fits You the best.

Comment: Hii Jabbasnik, Iam getting Precondition failed Exception in QA Environment, But in my local its working fine is there any Version related issues ? 

**ERROR:- liquibase.exception.preconditionfailedException: Precondition Failed Migration Failed for the change set change01.xml::change02.xml**

Comment: I guess it might be the problem. What is your QA environment liquibase version? Static on fail messages has been introduced in Liquibase 2.0. Take a look here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335280/liquibase-preconditions-failure-custom-error-message), maybe it will be helpful. You can also perform a check whether table exists first.